# Is Wordpress vulnerable to "comment posting forgery"?

Tags: comments, security

I recently scanned my Wordpress site using [6scan](http://6scan.com/)'s security scanning service.  It reported a high severity vulnerability: "Wordpress comment posting forgery".

Technical details from 6scan:

- The 6scan report says "CSRF vulnerability in allows malicious users to make fake posts".  It says the affected URL is /wp-comments-post.php.
- When I click the 6scan report's link for more technical details, it directs me to [this page](https://6scan.desk.com/customer/portal/articles/645159-zero-day-exploit), which is a generic page that refers to zero-day vulnerabilities (i.e., vulnerabilities disclosed to the Wordpress team but not publicly known).  However, that page hasn't been updated since July 17, 2012 (almost a year ago), and it has no specific mention of this CSRF vulnerability.
- The 6scan report also suggests a way to manually fix the problem: it suggests manually editing wp-comments-post.php to add some code that basically checks to make sure `$_SERVER[ "HTTP_REFERER" ]` matches `$_SERVER[ "HTTP_HOST" ]`.

I am running Wordpress 3.5.1 (currently the most recent version).  Is Wordpress really vulnerable to a "comment posting forgery" vulnerability?  Or is the 6scan report bogus?

I know that older versions of Wordpress had some CSRF vulnerabilities, but I believe those have been fixed.  Personally, I find the claim of a vulnerability pretty dubious -- but I thought I would check with others.

Answer (score 4):

This is a false alarm. Many “Security Programs” do that. That’s called [FUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt).

WordPress does not check the `Referer` header, because it is often empty, and real spammers send the site URL as `Referer` anyway.

But all comment field are sanitized, so no harmful code will be injected. Install an anti-spam plugin, and everything is fine. This report is obviously bogus.

Comment: Thanks.  This sounds like what I am looking for.  However, my one hesitation is: sanitizing comment fields is not enough to prevent CSRF attacks.  If there *is* indeed a CSRF vulnerability in comment posting, an anti-spam plugin is not the right solution; the right solution is to fix the CSRF vulnerability.  So, I'm still left wondering whether there is indeed a CSRF vulnerability in Wordpress or not.

Comment: @D.W. If there is an unknown vulnerability, we wouldn’t know it. If there is a _known_ vulnerability, it would be fixed already. There are many problems with WordPress, but security bugs are fixed amazingly fast.

Comment: Good point, toscho.  Thank you for the words of wisdom and sensible advice!

Answer (score -2):

You should always have Akismet activated.
It will catch 99.99% of spam comments.

Comment: This does not answer the question.